# In Flutter How to handle the passcode_screen's broadcast flag

Tags: flutter, broadcast

I have implemented my version of screen lock utility using the example at https://pub.dev/packages/passcode_screen/example but am not sure how to use the "_verificationNotifier" in my main.dart to route to my homepage when the user enters the correct passcode. Here is my main.dart

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'MyAppTitle',
      // home: SheetScreen(),
      home: LoginPage(),
    );
  }
}
```

And login page is almost exactly what is in the example. For now I am resorting to

```
if (isValid) {
        setState(() {
          this.isAuthenticated = isValid;
        });
        Navigator.pushReplacement(context,
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext ctx) => SheetScreen()));
```

I dont think that is correct, the purpose of the StreamController with a broadcast seems to be that this has to be "listened" to and routed appropriately. Can someone help with an example ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need a streamcontroller for this.

The way I manage it, I show my login page, when the user put their credentials and press the button, call my controller that will call the backend to verify the credentials. if succeed due to my use case I've saved it in a secure storage so that user is always locked, but you can skip this. Then return the value to the login page and push the new screen. See

```
void _login(context) async {
    String successLogin;
    if (_loginFormKey.currentState!.validate()) {
      successLogin =
          await login(emailInput.getValue(), passwordInput.getValue());

      if (successLogin != ERROR101 && successLogin == LOGGED) {

        Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
            HomePage.routeName, (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
      } else {
        showDialog(
            context: context,
            builder: (context) => ErrorAlert(
                title: AppLocalizations.of(context)!.errorOccurred,
                message: AppLocalizations.of(context)!.noAccountFound));
      }
    }
```

My controller:

```
Future<String> login(email, password) async {
  final response = await http.post(Uri.parse('$_baseUrl/auth/local'),
      body: {"identifier": email, "password": password});

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    dynamic body = jsonDecode(response.body);
    String jwt = body['jwt'];
    int userId = body['user']['id'];
    USERNAME = body['user']['firstName'];

    if (jwt != null) {
      await writeJWT(jwt);
      await writeUserStore(email);
      await writeUserId(userId);
      await writePassword(password);
      await writeRole(body['user']['role']['name']);
      USERLOGGED = true;
      return LOGGED;
    } else {
      return ERROR101;
    }
  } else {
    return ERROR101;
  }
}
```

As you can see I save some user information in memory for later use.

Comment: I have seen examples that use SharedPreferences (localStorage) to handle login. You are doing something similar. But I am assuming the author of the plugin put in the StreamController with broadcast for a reason. I am thinking it is some kind of hook to be used in main.dart